# simplexml_import_dom(): Invalid Nodetype to import - which DOMNode sub-types are supported?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

From time to time, the [`simplexml_import_dom()`](http://php.net/simplexml_import_dom) function gives me the following error when the passed [`DOMNode`](http://php.net/class.domnode) is not of a compatible sub-type:

> simplexml_import_dom(): Invalid Nodetype to import

So I'm wondering which `DOMNode` types are valid to import?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `DOMNode` you import via `simplexml_import_dom` must be associated to a document. That is independent of it's `DOMNode` sub-type, a node without a document will be rejected:

> simplexml_import_dom(): Imported Node must have associated Document

Next to that, the imported node must be of type [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/class.domelement).

And those two are the only requirements (see [source](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/simplexml/simplexml.c#2453)).

Summary: You can import any `DOMElement` which has a `ownerDocument` into simplexml.

If you need to import a `DOMNode` that has no document, create one and import it.

```
/** @var XMLReader $reader */
$node = $reader->expand();

if (!$node instanceof DOMElement) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException(
        sprintf('Expected DOMElement, %s given.', get_class($node))
    );
}

$doc  = new DomDocument();
$node = $doc->importNode($node, true);

$sxnl = simplexml_import_dom($node);
```

If the node is not a `DOMElement` then it is more tricky to work-around and depends on what you need in concrete, there is no simple fall-back, as much as there is no simple in simplexml at that point.

To find out which nodetype a SimpleXMLElement represents, please see:

- [How to tell apart SimpleXML objects representing element and attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/724935/367456)